# Wrong UIActionSheet layout in popover

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, uiactionsheet

I’ve got an `UIActionSheet` with a single button that I show in a popover. In landscape mode there is a plenty of space around the popover, so that it displays with an arrow in the middle and everything is fine:

[image: in landscape]

In portrait the popover has to be displayed with an arrow on the right side:

[image: in portrait]

Now the button looks a little bit too low and little bit too far to the right (it’s not the cropping). Have you met this behaviour? Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: No, we just put up with the wrong alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Looks strange?

Of the top of my head you could send the button a

```
[button sizeToFit]
```

message after it has been added to the popover. It's a long shot.